# equality of nulls in scala, odersky book's explanation seems different from scala code?

Tags: scala, null, equality

In the Odersky book "Programming in Scala" second edition, section 5.7 on page 89, the "==" operator is explained as:

> "As you see, == has been carefully crafted so that you get just the equality comparison you want in most cases.  This is accomplished with a very simple rule: first check the left side for null, and if it is not null, call the equals method...Since there is an automatic null check, you do not have to do the check yourself (7)"

Then the note "7":

> "The automatic check does not look at the right-hand side, but any reasonable equals method should return false if its argument is null."

If the null check doesn't look at the RHS, I was expecting null==anything to just always evaluate to false... but I tried it out, and null==null evaluates to true.

The book is based on scala 2.8.  Did the language change at some point, or am I just miss-understanding the explanation?

In a drools engine I used, == was interpreted such that if the LHS was null, and the RHS was not null, the equals method from the RHS would be passed the LHS.  Even though most reasonable equals methods should return false on nulls, I liked the way the drools engine handled this.  In SQL, I'm used to null != null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the quoted text only says what happens if LHS is not `null`, so there is no contradiction in that part. The description of what happens when LHS is `null` is perhaps in some part of the text you didn't quote or it's missing entirely.

Note (7) explains, that if the LHS is not `null`, then no check is performed on the RHS, RHS is just passed to `equals`. So when comparing something like `someExpression == null`, Scala first checks if `someExpression` isn't null and then calls `someExpression.equals(null)`.

I'd say that Scala's `term1 == term2` is converted into Java's

```
(term1 != null) ? term1.equals(term2) : (term2 == null)
```

(Note that this is a Java snippet so `==` in the above line means Java's reference equality.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is, how [`==` is implemented in AnyRef](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/library-aux/scala/AnyRef.scala#L80).

```
final def ==(that: AnyRef): Boolean =
    if (this eq null) that eq null
    else this equals that
```

`eq` is a method that checks if both variables reference the same object, so in this the case `null == null` both `eq null` checks in the third line of the snippet return true.